# Gitlabにファイル数1万以上 合計容量8GB のファイル群をcommit & push する方法

Tags: git, gitlab

ファイルの数がとにかく多いファイル群をまとめて Gitlab にpushしたいです。
tortoise Git を使ってますが、すべてのファイルを push しても commit できません。

どうすればファイル数も容量も多いファイル群を push できるか教えていただけないでしょうか

Comment: この辺のヘルプ記事 [Account and limit settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html), [Git Large File Storage (LFS)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/index.html), [GitLab application limits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/instance_limits.html) を調べるか、サポート窓口に問い合わせしてみてはどうでしょう？ Git LFSには「一般的な推奨事項は、パフォーマンスを維持するために1GBを超えるGitリポジトリを使用しないことです。」とあるようですが。

Answer (score 3):

１つのプロジェクトのソースコードが 8GB に達するとはとても思えないので `*.o` `*.obj` 等オブジェクトファイル等の中間形式であるとか `*.EXE` `*.DLL` 等最終生成物とかも含んでいたり、あるいは動画ファイルとか BGM 音楽ファイルとか、ソースコードとして管理するのが適切であるとは思えないものとかも含んでいる可能性があります。

真にソースコードが 8GB あるとしたら、プロジェクトを分割しましょう。おそらくそのサイズだと人間の管理能力を超えています。

`git` に限らずソースコード管理ツールに中間・最終生成物を登録するのはほぼ無意味です。適切に分類して `.gitignore` を書き「管理不必要」なものは除外しましょう。

差分を取ることに意味がないバイナリファイルは (web storage に/git 外に) ファイルそのままを保存しておくほうが単純でよいでしょう。そのほうが高速です。

`git` 自体もそんなに容量を食わせると性能が出なくなり「遅くて使えねー」からあなたの同僚たちが使わなくなってしまうかもしれません。

ということで現代的コンピュータのハードウエア・ソフトウエア的に制約があるのは仕方ないことなので、もうちょっと運用を再検討してみてください。普通はそういう運用はしないです。